# IndexedDB get empty multiEntry index

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have an objectstore with multiEntry-index where some rows have an empty array, meaning they will still show up as being indexed, but without content. How do I query those?

I have tried, without success:

```
index.getAll(IDBKeyRange.only(""))

index.getAll(IDBKeyRange.only([]))
```

When checking the Chrome developer tools under Application -> IndexeDB, the entries shows up as [] when checking content under correct index.